# Show tkinter widget when checkbox is checked

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, checkbox

I'm trying to make the entry widget show once the checkbutton is checked and hide when it's not.

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.geometry('500x400')
other = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="Other", variable=other, command=toggle()).grid(row=10, sticky=W)
def toggle():
    if other.get()==1:
        Entry(master,width=50).grid(row=11, sticky=W)
    else:
        Entry(master,width=50).grid_remove()
```

Comment: Part of the problem is because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Comment: try using `Checkbutton(......,command=lambda:toggle())` so you can callback that function

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

def toggle():
    if other.get():
        ent.grid(row=11, sticky=W)
    else:
        ent.grid_forget()

master = Tk()
master.geometry('500x400')
other = BooleanVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="Other", variable=other, command=toggle).grid(row=10, sticky=W)
ent=Entry(master,width=50)
master.mainloop()
```